# How to deploy to path returned by GetClassResourcePath?

Tags: visual-studio, web-part

I'm using VS 2010 to create a SP 2010 web part.  I want to include my images, css files and js files in the VS project, and have them be deployed to the correct location.  My understanding is that I should be using `SPWebPartManager.GetClassResourcePath()` to get the urls for these items, and that the files should end up in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\wpresources\{web part name}\{version}__{pk token}`.

1. Is the above correct, or is there a better way?
2. How to I include these fines in the VS project so that they are deployed to this location - e.g. is there a SharePoint mapped folder I have to put them in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deploy it to the wpresources location then you add the resources to the SPI (SharePoint item) in Visual Studio. For instance righ-click on a Web Part item and then add an existing item. Select the new item and look at its properties (F4) and check the Deployment Type. It should be set to *NoDeployment* by default. Change it to *ClassResource*...tada...done!

This will add the necessary XML elements (ClassResources/ClassResource) to your package

Comment: Awesome!  It looks like I have to set this property per-file rather than per-folder (e.g. every image instead of the images folder).  Is there quicker way?

Comment: You have to set it per file so that VS adds it automatically to the solution package.